# QGIS Processing - Edge Extraction

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-processing, orfeo-toolbox

I am looking for QGIS function to extract (or detect) edge from a raster, which was referred in here, [How to digitize a raster automatically](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68076/how-to-digitize-a-raster-automatically?rq=1) as answer by @MappaGnosis.

The name could have changed since then, or it may have been integrated into other tool... I cannot find it in my QGIS Processing Toolbox (2.14.10 and 2.18.2).

There are similar tools such as GRASS "i.zc Zero-crossing" and SAGA "Gaussian filter", but I am hoping to find this QGIS geoalgorithm.

Comment: It seems that the link you provided refers to vector analysis: do you want a raster or a vector as output?

Comment: Yes, @HowToInQGIS, thank you for pointing that. What I want is to have the edge (or sharp change) as a vector (linestring). If the tool returns a raster, I think I can turn it to vector. So both cases would do for me.

Comment: @Joseph Thank you so much! I had never installed Orfeo Toolbox, so it was a bit challenging... but it was worth trying. Now I can see so many Edge Extraction(s), including Sobel filter. Wow.

Comment: @Kazuhito - Most welcome, glad it was helpful! Will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *Edge Extraction* tool may have been moved to the **Orfeo Toolbox** as this focuses on image analysis. The Orfeo Toolbox contains a number of edge extraction tools using various methods such as:

- [EdgeExtraction (gradient)](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/otb/feature_extraction.html#edgeextraction-gradient)
- [EdgeExtraction (sobel)](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/otb/feature_extraction.html#edgeextraction-sobel)
- [EdgeExtraction (touzi)](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/otb/feature_extraction.html#edgeextraction-touzi)