# Automatic geometry creation

Tags: shapefile, polygon-creation

I am currently slowly mapping field boundaries of old agriculture map areas using QGIS. Has anyone designed a magic plugin or method so that the black outlines of the boundaries are automatically detected. A bit like finding edges in photoshop. I realise that some manual editing would be required, but I thought I would ask.

Comment: Have a look at the answer provided in this link: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68076/digitizing-raster-automatically great thing about this site is chances are someone has already asked the question you want to ask

Comment: That post seems to have been from 2013 and the plug ins mentioned no longer exist (A better option in QGIS might be to use the Edge Extraction feature in the Sextante Plugin (now called 'Processing'). The edge extration look useful. I'm using QGIS 3 so has it been incorpotated into full download (not plugin)?