# extract roads, railways and canals out of old orthophoto

Tags: feature-extraction, orthophoto

how is it possible to extract the roads, canals and or railways out of this image (black-white)?

Or how is possible to create lines at the edges of the roads, canals and or railways?
[image]

Comment: This related post may be of interest: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/48315/8104.  What software are you working with?

Comment: Qgis or Arcgis, but normally some other free software is also possible