# Extracting Roads and Trails from SPOT Imagery

Tags: raster, vector, feature-extraction, image-segmentation

Is it possible to extract Roads and Trails vectors from SPOT Raster Tiff Image? Actually I have tried SPRING software to extract road vectors from this raster. Yes, It gives good result, But unfortunately it extracts road data only. It fails to extract trails. I have shared a sample data via Google Drive,FYI EPSG: 26913

Anyone had succeeded extracting low width trails/Roads? If yes, please guide me to achieve it.I want to extract the data as polyline or polygon data.(any Free software to do this task would be much helpful)
[image]

Link for Sample TIFF [SPOT_SAMPLE TIFF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2MpktiU0N1CTWFFNDJZV1FfN1k/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you considered edge detection algorithms in Python? http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/#edges-and-lines

Comment: For those whom extracting roads is enough see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48308/extracting-roads-out-of-landsat-raster-images?rq=1